# Rails 3, changing a specific value in a row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This question seems ridiculously easy, but I seem to be stuck.

Lets say we have a table "Books"

Each Book, has a name, description, and a status.

Lets say I want to create link in the show view, that when clicked, solely changes the status (to "read") for example.

So far, I've tried adding a block in the controller, that says:

```
def read

  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @book.status = "Read"
  @book.update_attributes(params[:book])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back}
    format.xml  { render :xml => @book }
  end

end
```

Then I've added a link to the view that is like: 
<%= link_to "Read", read_book_path(@book), :method => :put %>

This isn't working at all. I have added it to my routes, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

-Elliot

EDIT: Forgot to add I'm getting a NoMethodError: undefined method `read_book_path'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a method called read:

```
def read
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])

  @book.status = "Read"
  @book.save
end
```

Then you want <%= link_to "Read", read_book_path(@book), :remote => true %>

and in routes.rb:

```
resources :books do
  member do
    get 'read'
  end
end
```

Once that works, mess around with changing the method to :put

Comment: hey Seth, Thanks for the answer! When I tried it exactly as you said I seem to get the same NoMethodError: "undefined method `read_book_path' for"

Comment: Actually, it worked! I had collection in my route instead of member! Thanks!

Comment: double check your pluralization. resourceS :bookS. Run "rake routes" from console and post it please

Comment: yay :) can you mark me as correct and up-vote :). Once you get the hang of routes, you'll figure these things much faster

Comment: Elliot, use 'rake routes' to display the list of available routes you have.  Until you see your route in that list your routes.rb is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is set the `status` attribute on a book and not update any other parameters, then calling update_attributes is unnecessary.

change:

```
@book.update_attributes(params[:book])
```

to:

```
@book.save!
```